# How can I go to the error line code in Visual Studio Code's Java Debug Console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So currently, I have just moved from Intellij to Visual Studio Code to develop my personal Java Spring Boot Application.

The problem is that when Java Debug Console shows exceptions like the below image, it's underlining when I hover to that link. It doesn't have a function like click to point at that line of error code.

So Are there any extensions or configs to do to solve this problem?

[image: My Java Debug Console]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Click` the exception in **Terminal** will enter `.class` file you referred in your project.

But focus on the sentences where includes your `.java` file, then pressing `Ctrl+Click` will redirect you to the source code.